# How to insert one html page into another html page using custom directive in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Using custom directives, I want to add one HTML page into another, how can this be done?
The custom directive is as below:

```
(this is the .js file)
 fbModule.directive('fbLogin', function(){
        return {
            template : html
        }        
 })
```

And the html page to be included is:

```
(this is the .html file to be included)
<div ng-controller="fbCtrl">
    <button ng-click="doFacebookLogin">
        <img src="modules/shippingAddress/fastfill_fb.png" width="140px" height="25px;" style="margin-right: 8px; cursor:pointer">
    </button>
</div>
```

The page inside which the above code should come is:

```
(this is the .html file in which the above html should come)
<div fbLogin></div>
<div style="font-size: x-small; color: black;">Save on typing. Use your FB data.</div>
```

Please help..
Thanks in advance

Comment: take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change **template** to **templateUrl** if you need to get the external html like as shown below.

> **templateUrl** can also be a function which returns the URL of an HTML
>   template to be loaded and used for the directive. Angular will call
>   the templateUrl function with two parameters: the element that the
>   directive was called on, and an attr object associated with that
>   element.

[**Working Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/34gbAQD9glK3Nbo0oJja?p=preview)

```
  fbModule.directive('fbLogin', function() {
    return {
      template: 'template.html'
    };
  });
```

to

```
  fbModule.directive('fbLogin', function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'template.html'
    };
  });
```

Comment: Cool.. Thanks... Its a module within the same application, it started working with `template` too..

Answer (score 2):

You should be using ngInclude to inject HTML into another page
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

```
<ng-include src="somehtmlfile.html"></ng-include>
```

Comment: No, to add extra functionality we have to keep the code in modules, hence cant use 'ng-include'.

Answer (score 0):

Basically:

```
 fbModule.directive('fbLogin', function(){
         return {
             templateUrl : "...path to html"
         }});
```

...but read the Developers Guide https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 0):

use templateUrl instead of template. your templateUrl must point to the html file in directory.
here my templeUrl points to my.html that is inside template directory.

```
fbModule.directive('fbLogin', function(){
        return {
            templateUrl : "/templates/my.html"
        }        
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely replace directive tag with html file loaded by directive you should use `templateUrl: 'path/to/file.html'` and `replace: true` so your directive tag gets replaced by html instead of being included into it.
Here is the directive example:

```
app.directive('fbLogin', function(){
  return {
      templateUrl : 'include.html',
      replace: true
  }        
});
```

Also, here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yOOGQsqm3xd9uAbFBJRm?p=preview).